# Reading InputStream after writing

Tags: android, inputstream, httpurlconnection, outputstream, urlconnection

I am trying to read `InputStream` after writing output stream to `sdcard`. I have downloaded file from `HttpURLConnection`. File is successfuly written to sdcard. But I am trying to read `inputstream` from `same file` but contents are not being read properly. On `emulator` some contents are shown but `on actual device` contents are not shown. Can you please help what can be the issue? I am posting `downloading`, `writing` and `reading code`.

```
fileUrl = new URL(filename);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)fileUrl.openConnection();
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();

/**
* Create file with input stream
*/
File downloadFile = new File("/sdcard/", "myFile3.pdf");
downloadFile.createNewFile();
final FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(downloadFile);

int availbleLength = is.available();
byte[] bytes = new byte[availbleLength];
int len1 = 0;
while ((len1 = is.read(bytes)) > 0) {
    outputStream.write(bytes, 0, len1);
}
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();

File myFile = new File("/sdcard/myFile3.pdf");
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(myFile);

byte[] buffer = new byte[inputStream.available()];
inputStream.read(buffer);
System.out.println("Byte Lenght: " + buffer.length);
```

Comment: are you getting garbage data or truncated data or nothing ?

Comment: I am getting nothing.

Comment: are u able to open file directly from sdcard ?

Comment: Yes I am able to open. I am using [link](https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library) library to parse and show the pdf in application. After opening its contents are not being parse and shown

Comment: do u mean u opened in pdf reader? ... i would suggest to experiment the library by reading an existing pdf file not one u created and figure out issue with writing file or reading file...

Comment: Its wokring locally. After testing, I have gone to `HttpURLConnection`.

Comment: Maybe you could read the answers of one of the other 4 posts you created today?

Answer (score 0):

inputStream.available() is only an estimate not actual length of the complete input data.

[FileInputStream.available()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileInputStream.html#available%28%29)